# How do I figure out what the distribution of X is?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to figure out what distribution X follows in this question:

Of the people passing by a luxury clothing shop 0.4% make
a purchase. Let X be the number of those who will make a purchase
amongst a randomly selected group of 1000 people who passed by the
shop

Right now I think it's a hypergeometric distribution because from what I can see it doesn't seem to match any other type of distribution (I'm probably wrong on this). But I can't figure out the parameters for M, N and n if it is indeed hypergeometric.

Answer (score 0):

There are two outcomes when a person walks by the luxury clothing shop, they either buy something or they don't. When there are only two outcomes a specific distribution should come to mind. Hint: Latin for having two.

Comment: Oh wow, it's binomial...I'm so foolish..Thanks!

Comment: I believe it is, happens to everyone.